# How to use "Continue as {name}" Facebook button with Rails + Devise + Oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I've successfully added a **Sign in with Facebook** feature to my Rails 5 app with Devise and Omniauth.

Instead of my static button, I'd like to implement Facebook's embed "Continue as {name}" [login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/). In their documentation they'll produce the following code for you to implement:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

[image: First button is Facebook's own and second one is mine]

Just implementing it like that obviously doesn't work. I'd really like to be able to handle it in a way where I can specify it to direct to my `user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path`. How do I do that?

I've implemented Facebook SDK on the website.

Thank you in advance. Your help is much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Omniauth uses the server-side login flow, whereas this button is part of the client-side login flow.

Only by being embedded on the client side can it determine whether there is a logged-in Facebook user in the first place - on the server side, that info isn’t available.

The server- and the client-side auth flow have quite significant differences, so I doubt you would be able to implement this, without rewriting how login is handled almost completely.